# Convert CURL request into javascript

Tags: javascript, curl, axios

Can you please help me to convert this curl post request into a javascript(Axios) request?

```
    
https://url.com/api/send.php

function send_sms($url,$apikey,$smsno=1,$destination,$content){
    $fields = array(
       'apikey' => $apikey,
       'smsno' => $smsno,
       'destination' => $destination,
       'content' => $content
    );
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: If you have a Bash curl command (not PHP code), you can use https://curlconverter.com/node-axios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example will do the job:

```js
function send_sms(apikey, smsno, destination, content){
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://url.com/api/send.php',
        data: {
            apikey: apikey,
            smsno: smsno,
            destination: destination,
            content: content
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [fetch](https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/) can help you convert a CURL command to fetch code.

Since fetch is open source, you can **modify** or **extend** the source code at will.

---

You can also copy a request recorded with the Chrome DevTools as a fetch.

[image: https://github.com/kigiri]

Source: [kigiri](https://github.com/kigiri)